# How to get Ajax post request by symfony2 Controller

Tags: ajax, symfony

I send text message like this

html markup

```
<textarea id="request" cols="20" rows="4"></textarea>
```

javascript code

```
var data = {request : $('#request').val()};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('acme_member_msgPost') }}",
    data: data,
    success: function (data, dataType) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

symfony2 controller code

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$text = $request->request->get('data');
```

but `$text` is null ...

I have tried normal post request (not Ajax) by firefox http request tester.

```
/app_dev.php/member/msgPost
```

Controller works and `$text` has a value.

So I think the php code is OK, there is the problem on Ajax side, however

'success:function' is called as if succeeded.

How can you get the contents of javascript data structure?

Comment: Try this one in your controller `$text = $this->getRequest()->get('request');`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, you don't need to access the container in your controller as it already implements `ContainerAware`

So basically your code should look like this in your `Controller.php`

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->get('request');
}
```

Also, make sure by the data you are sending is not null by using `console.log(data)` in the JS of your application.

**And finally the answer of your question** : you are not using the right variable, you need to access the value of `$('#request').val()` but you stored it in a `request` variable and you used a `data` variable name in your controller.

Consider changing the name of the variable, because it's confusing.

Answer (score 24):

If you're sending the data as JSON — not as form urlencoded — you need to access the request body directly:

```php
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong when obtaining the value, you must use:

```
$data = $request->request->get('request');
```

'cause **request** is the name of your parameter.