# Symfony2: UnitTests for AJAX Controllers

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, phpunit

I'm going to write some Symfony2 UnitTests (derived from Symfony\ Bundle\ FrameworkBundle\ Test\ WebTestCase) to test ajax controllers, similar to this [How to get Ajax post request by symfony2 Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826821/how-to-get-ajax-post-request-by-symfony2-controller).
My big problem is to get the parameters into the "request" bag of the request, not into the "parameter" bag. Similar to the upper example the method in the controller looks like this:

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request) 
{
    $data = $request->request->get('data');
}
```

But if i do a var_dump of the $request, the paramaters i supply in the WebTestCase do not appear in $request->**request**, but in $request->**parameter**. Let's say this is the portion of code in my webtestcase:

```
....
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/ajax/blahblah', ... ?????);
```

I already tried supplying the parameter(s) directly within the url as

```
/ajax/blahblah?data=whocares
```

I tried specifying the parameter within an array

```
$client->request('POST', '/ajax/blahblah', array('data' => 'fruityloops'));
```

But nothing worked. Any chance to get this running?

Thanks in advance

Hennes

Answer (score 0):

After you make the request, you need to get the response. Try this:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('POST', '/ajax/blahblah', array('data' => 'fruityloops'));
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

//convert to array
$data = json_decode($response->getContent(true), true);

var_dump($data);
$this->assertArrayHasKey('your_key', $data);
```